# scrape data from interactive chart using selenium, bs4 or requests

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from charts on this page: http://188.166.44.172/match/live-stats/100941310

I tried requests and bs4, but failed to get any data, I also tried with selenium and no data as well.

Here's the code using requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u, timeout=30, headers=headers)    

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('rect'):
    if i.has_attr("onmouseover"):
        text = i.get('onmouseover')
        print(text)
```

And the code using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
u = "http://188.166.44.172/match/live-stats/100941310"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options)

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('rect'):   #I also tried soup.select('*')
    if i.has_attr("onmouseover"):
        text = i.get('onmouseover')
        print(text)
```

Is there's any way to scrape data from those charts using python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting anything back is because all the charts are generated dynamically by `JavaScript` and with, for example, `bs4` you won't read any of this.

However, the data for the charts is embedded in the `HTML`. You could parse that and plot.

Here's how:

```
import ast
import re

import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

target_url = "http://188.166.44.172/match/live-stats/100941310"
page_source = requests.get(target_url).text

raw_attack_data = ast.literal_eval(
    re.search(r"var all_attack = (\[.*\])", page_source).group(1),
)
all_attack = [i[1] for i in raw_attack_data if isinstance(i, list)]

plt.plot(all_attack, label="attack")
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

This should give you a plot like this:

[image]

As I've said, eveyrthing you need is in the source code, so you'd have to play around with the values.

The source looks like this:

[image]

Where the first value of the inner list is the game time and the second value is the stat that's plotted on the charts.

Note that some arrays have values in `{}`. These' are those icon markers on the charts. You can filter them out with `isistance(i, list)` since these can be easily parsed as `dicts`, as I've shown above.

EDIT:

Yes, it's possible to get division and team info, as everything is in the `HTML`. I've reworked the initial answer a bit and came up with this:

```py
import ast
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

target_url = "http://188.166.44.172/match/live-stats/100941310"
page_source = requests.get(target_url).text


def get_match_info(html_source: str) -> list:
    return [
        i.getText(strip=True) for i
        in BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml").select("h1 a")
    ]


def get_stats(html_source: str, search_str: str) -> tuple:
    raw_data = ast.literal_eval(
        re.search(fr"var {search_str} = (\[.*\])", html_source).group(1),
    )
    filtered = [i[1] for i in raw_data if isinstance(i, list)]
    game_time = [i[0] for i in raw_data if isinstance(i, list)]
    return game_time, filtered


division, home, away = get_match_info(page_source)

time_, attack_home = get_stats(page_source, "dangerous_home")
_, attack_away = get_stats(page_source, "dangerous_away")

plt.suptitle(f"{division} - {home} v {away}")
plt.ylabel("Attack")
plt.xlabel("Game time")
plt.plot(time_, attack_home, color="blue", label=home)
plt.plot(time_, attack_away, color="black", label=away)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

This produces a plot:

[image]

Comment: it's really great work, from the data scraped, we can know exactly which team for each stat ?

Comment: is there's any way to know the data for each specific team ?

Comment: @KhaledKoubaa yes, there's a way. I've updated the answer. If you find it useful, consider up-voting and/or accepting it.

Comment: How I could find the variables in the page source using my browser? How I should find and see "var all_attacks" (in your image related to page source) in my browser to use?

Comment: Could you please tell me how could I find variables for the interactive chart of this page? https://www.fxempire.com/macro/canada/consumer-confidence